# Deploying django project on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following the tutorial for deploying a django project on AWS elastic beanstalk here:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

My app works when I test locally but when I deploy, I'm getting a 404 error. Looking at the event logs, I see this message:

`Error running user's commands : An error occurred running '. /opt/python/ondeck/env && PYTHONPATH=/opt/python/ondeck/app: django-admin.py syncdb --noinput' (rc: 127) /bin/sh: django-admin.py: command not found`

That leads me to believe that the tutorial is missing a part about installing django files on the server or at least configuring my project to recognize django-admin.py. I have django installed on my local machine so it works there.

I know python support is brand new for elastic beanstalk but has anyone deployed django to it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you don't need to put container_commands in .config because there is no database or table at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

Did you made the step?: Freeze the requirements.txt file.

```
(djangodev)# pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Note
Make sure your requirements.txt file contains the following:

```
Django==1.4.1
MySQL-python==1.2.3
```

I had the same problem because I skipped it. Once I did it, add, commit and push. It works!

Comment: I figured I'd pipe up as well - I had the exact same problem. I originally skipped the steps that create the environment, as I'm working with some pretty simple steps. It would seem that it requires both a requirements.txt, as well as valid configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same tutorial recently and had a similar result.

At step 6, upon seeing the default django 'congrats' page render locally, I deployed to EB as instructed and got a 404 instead of the default 'congrats' page.

I decided to use the code up to that point as a foundation for following the  '[getting started with django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)' which led me to a successful rendering of a 'home' view. This is a much more useful place to be anyway. I do agree that there is something wrong with the AWS tutorial and posted to the AWS forums [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=103117&tstart=0).

Answer (score 1):

If you can, you should try to access the log file; it might give you a better idea of what's going on.   Here's a link that might help:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html